# Redirect to nested controller action

Tags: laravel-6

I recently moved my controllers to an `Admin` directory.

- I changed the namespace: `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;`
- I have included the `Controller` class: `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;`

In my controller, I have a redirect to the controller's `index()` action.

```php
return redirect()->action('ServiceController@index');
```

Now I get the following error:

> InvalidArgumentException Action
>   App\Http\Controllers\ServiceController@index not defined.

I can't figure out how to declare the new action redirect in the docs so I am posting my question here.

**Routes**

```php
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectController');
    Route::resource('services', 'ServiceController');
    Route::resource('projectFiles', 'ProjectFileController');
    Route::get('seed', 'SeedController@seedDatabase')->name('seed');
});
```

This is the part of the controller where I am talking about:

```php
class ServiceController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.services.index', [
            'services' => Service::all()
        ]);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.services.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            Service::create([
                'name' => $request->name,
                'machine_name' => snake_case($request->name),
                'description' => $request->description
            ]);

            return redirect()->action('\App\Htpp\Controllers\Admin\ServiceController@index');
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            throw $th;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `use` statement somewhere on top? Like `use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ServiceController`

Comment: I do the redirect in the same controller @kerbholz

Comment: Do you want to redirect to a different page after storing some data? I usually redirect to the `route` and not the action: `return redirect()->route('services.index');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer, but anyone can correct me if I am wrong.

In `RouteServiceProvider` the namespace is set to `App\Http\Controllers`:

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

So I decided to add Admin\ before the name of the controller and now the redirect works:

```
return redirect()->action('Admin\ServiceController@index');
```